# How to make a single-AZ (non-HA) RDS instance with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, high-availability

In [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-converting-a-single-az-amazon-rds-instance-to-a-multi-az-instance/) AWS Database Blog, they assert that

> You can set up Amazon RDS in a Single-AZ database (DB) instance or a
> Multi-AZ DB instance for high availability requirements

and that you can

> ...modify existing Single-AZ instances to become Multi-AZ deployments.

Furthermore,

> ...you can create a Multi-AZ read replica, synchronize it with your
> Single-AZ DB instance, and then promote it as your primary DB instance
> to minimize latencies during conversion.

Additionally, in v1.32 of the official [AWS VPC Module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/1.32.0) there are multiple references to the usage of [single_nat_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/1.32.0#nat-gateway-scenarios), particularly

> If single_nat_gateway = true, then all private subnets will route
> their Internet traffic through this single NAT gateway.

and in the official RDS module, `multi_az` is shown as defaulting to `false` ([link](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/latest#input_multi_az)).

Despite this, I am getting the following error

```
╷
│ Error: DBSubnetGroupDoesNotCoverEnoughAZs: The DB subnet group doesn't meet Availability Zone (AZ) coverage requirement. Current AZ coverage: us-west-2a. Add subnets to cover at least 2 AZs.
│   status code: 400, request id: *****
│ 
│   with module.rds.module.db_subnet_group.aws_db_subnet_group.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/rds/modules/db_subnet_group/main.tf line 8, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "this":
│    8: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "this" {
```

when attempting to `terraform apply` this `main.tf` configuration:

```
module "rds" {
  source                                = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version                               = "~> 3.4.0"
  identifier                            = "${var.env}-${var.user}-${local.db_name}"
  engine                                = var.postgres.engine
  engine_version                        = var.postgres.engine_version
  family                                = var.postgres.family
  major_engine_version                  = var.postgres.major_engine_version
  instance_class                        = var.postgres.instance_class
  allocated_storage                     = var.postgres.allocated_storage
  max_allocated_storage                 = var.postgres.max_allocated_storage
  storage_encrypted                     = var.postgres.storage_encrypted
  password                              = random_password.password.result
  port                                  = var.postgres.port
  multi_az                              = false
  subnet_ids                            = [data.aws_subnet.priv1.id]
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [module.db_security_group.security_group_id]
  maintenance_window                    = var.postgres.maintenance_window
  backup_window                         = var.postgres.backup_window
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = var.postgres.enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports
  backup_retention_period               = var.postgres.backup_retention_period
  skip_final_snapshot                   = var.postgres.skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection                   = var.postgres.deletion_protection
  performance_insights_enabled          = var.postgres.performance_insights_enabled
  performance_insights_retention_period = var.postgres.performance_insights_retention_period
  create_monitoring_role                = var.postgres.create_monitoring_role
  monitoring_role_name                  = "${var.env}-${var.user}-${var.postgres.monitoring_role_name}"
  monitoring_interval                   = var.postgres.monitoring_interval
  snapshot_identifier                   = var.postgres.snapshot_identifier
  iam_database_authentication_enabled   = var.postgres.iam_auth
  apply_immediately                     = true
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}-${var.user}-rds"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = var.env
    Created     = timestamp()
  }
}
```

with this `postgres` variable defined in my `terraform.tfvars`:

```
postgres = {
  db_name = "postgres-db"
  # All available versions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts
  engine                                = "postgres"
  engine_version                        = "11.12"
  family                                = "postgres11" # DB parameter group
  major_engine_version                  = "11"         # DB option group
  instance_class                        = "db.t2.micro"
  allocated_storage                     = 100
  max_allocated_storage                 = 200
  storage_encrypted                     = false
  port                                  = 5432
  multi_az                              = false
  maintenance_window                    = "Mon:00:00-Mon:03:00"
  backup_window                         = "03:00-06:00"
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["postgresql", "upgrade"]
  backup_retention_period               = 0
  skip_final_snapshot                   = true
  deletion_protection                   = false
  performance_insights_enabled          = false
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  create_monitoring_role                = true
  monitoring_role_name                  = "monitoring_role"
  monitoring_interval                   = 60
  snapshot_identifier                   = "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:999999999999:snapshot:rds-ss"
  iam_auth                              = true
}
```

Similar questions on SO seem to all have answers with the theme that you *must* provide multiple availability zones, which implies at least two subnets, which - if you are creating them manually as private subnets - would then each need their own NAT gateway.  That seems unnecessarily expensive and constraining, especially for development and test environments.

How can I deploy a single-az RDS Postgres instance with these components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DB subnet group has to have multiple subnets. That's a requirement of RDS that you can't bypass. Even if you are only deploying a single instance, if that entire availability zone were to go down, Amazon RDS would automatically spin up a new instance in one of the other availability zones you have specified. That's one of the managed database services that you get automatically with Amazon RDS.

So even if you are deploying a single-az instance, you have to specify multiple availability zones in the DB subnet group.

Comment: comment 1 for more context: in my config, I specify no db subnet groups, only a sg for the two EC2 instances I have in my public subnet, and `db_security_group` with `ingress`/`egress_with_source_security_group_id`s set to that sg.  I am making my 2 private subnets manually, each in their own az, and my deployment works if I give them both to the rds's `subnet_ids` parameter as a list.

Comment: comment 2: what's your thought on providing the public nat (which needs an eip) - do I really have do provide one nat for each private subnet, even if `multi_az = false`?

Comment: Comment 1: Yes that's the same thing I'm talking about. You have to provide at least two subnets for your database, even if you will only ever have one instance running. Comment 2: You don't need a NAT at all for RDS. If you have other services inside the private subnet you may need a NAT, but that's an entirely separate subject.

Comment: i want the RDS to be private as it contains PII, though. as well, I have lambdas that are reading and writing to the RDS in question, which iirc do have the private subnet requirement and also need to communicate with the external web, so if i have to have two AZs via two subnets, I think I'll need two nats (and therefore two eips) no?

Comment: RDS doesn't need to connect to the external web, so it can be in a private subnet without a NAT Gateway route. If you decide to create a NAT, you can have one NAT per VPC, or one per AZ, it depends on if you want failover in case of a regional AWS outage.

Comment: I'm not sure when this became a requirement. I currently have a running RDS replica which is single AZ, and in it's subnet group there is only subnets from a single AZ. I have created it with terraform a while ago, but now I can't update it, as I get the same error as OP.